# Legacy system has static members for Database Connections. Is this dangerous?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis

We have this huge legacy system. It has a bug that's been around for a while where 1 out of 10000 requests, a method that's supposed to return a very well known ID from a very little table (10 rows) returns a "crazy" value that, to our surprise, is almost always the id of another table of your system. This method only runs a simple SELECT query on the database.

We have noticed that there are two classes (one related to the place where the bug seems to be) that use a static member for the database connection:

```
    public class Accounts
    {
        private static Database db;

        private static Database DB
        {
            get
            {
                if (db == null)
                {
                    db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
                }
                return db;
            }
        }

 ...

}
```

Is this dangerous? We are not sure if this may bring thread safe issues, like the bug we mentioned before, which sounds a lot like a synchronization bug.

Comment: Having a static member for the database, can't be dangerous accross requests?

Comment: Well this code can call "db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();" more than once - you should lock that section to avoid that. The real question is your "Database" class thread safe?

Comment: @Sam, not sure, it's not a class of mine, it's a class from a Microsoft library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb748674(v=pandp.31)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/bb746629(v%3dpandp.31)

Comment: I guess that "CreateDatabase()" returns some specific implementation of "Database" - If you can't find documentation stating clearly that it is thread safe, I'd guess that it's instance members are probably not thread safe and you'll need a new instance per thread.

Comment: @itsme86 no - It's a race condition as there's no locking : A thread can do the null check, then start the work of setting the value, while another thread does the null check on "db" again ...

Comment: @Sam it's interesting the race condition you mention. However, I have not threads. This is an ASP.NET application. Do you mean different requests may initialize the variable ? Do requests run on different threads?

Comment: - Yeah - ASP Net requests (will usually) run on different threads!  The reassignment of db is probably a non-issue, but the shared use of a non thread safe object would result in erratic behaviour ...

Comment: @Sam, I'm confused. There's another class that has a private (NON STATIC) db member, that's the one receiving an odd value from a select query. Can't see why this class, which doesn't have a static Database member would have thread issues due to other class having static Database members... any ideas?

Comment: Where does it get the value for it's non-static property from though? - The issue is not the property being static, it's the sharing of an object in multiple threads. Is it possible that your non-static version still gets it's value from a similar static factory method to the one listed here?

Comment: @Sam, yes it does get the value from an exact copy of the method listed here, but instead of being static it's a private member where it stores it

Comment: @Sam, do you suggest something ? I mean, that race condition having something to do with the bug I described? Still can't get how it happens.

Comment: @mjwills why...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174223/discussion-between-sam-and-stephen-h-anderson).